# proof background required for Courant's "Introduction to Calculus and Analysis"?

Tags: calculus, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am considering reading Courant and John's famous *Introduction to Calculus and Analysis* as a reintroduction to, and to expand my understanding of, calculus. I was reading reviews on Amazon, and one reviewer said:

```
While Courant's insistence on proof does mean that the student needs to have a 
basic grounding in proof methods, this is usually a standard part of the 
undergraduate curriclum.
```

How much understanding of proofs do you think is necessary? I have read a few proofs in an introductory statistics textbook and seemed to understand them, but I don't have any sort of background in "formal proof theory," if there is such a thing.

Do you think any other books are a prerequisite and if so which ones?

Comment: Courant was my first introduction to rigorous mathematics (proof based). lt will be tough, but you'll learn a lot.

Comment: Thanks to everybody who has replied with questions and comments so far. I am extremely new and need all the help I can get! But with a good teacher in the form of a book, I think I can go far.

Comment: Let me add, Courant doesn't use set-builder notation. This is a drawback as almost any other mathematics book WILL use set-builder notation. Perhaps practice that notation elsewhere, if you want to continue with Courant.

Comment: Thanks. I know the basics of set-builder notation from my programming background (it is used in Python) as well as my introductory statistics book. Will I be missing out on a whole lot of calculus that traditionally uses this, or do you just mean I ought to know what it is? i.e. you don't think this makes the book outdated, do you?

Comment: You won't be missing out on anything. I am just saying you need to know what it is and be comfortable with it.

Comment: Well, I spent all day trying to break into Courant, and I got through 13 pages understanding almost all of it, but I'm not sure if I will continue. My goal was to learn calculus, and I love theory so I figured I should go for the most rigorous textbook. But I wasn't prepared for the fact that that means 100 pages about numbers before even getting to integrals. I know I was spoiled by high school where derivatives+integrals are immediately introduced, but I didn't expect the opposite extreme to be so extreme. Something to come back to, maybe. Rant over :)

Comment: Spivak's writing seems slightly more accessible, so maybe that will be my next step. And while I am loath to skip pages, I will probably just skip straight to the derivatives chapter. (I was trying to learn this for work so I don't have unlimited time)

Answer (score 1):

You won't need much of a background. Books like that are designed to be first courses in proofs. If you want, you could use something like Richard Hammock's "[The Book of Proof](http://www.people.vcu.edu/~rhammack/BookOfProof/)" to get a quick introduction to proof logic, and then head into Courant.

Answer (score 1):

I think that one the best way to develop proof skills is to solve demonstrative problems. There are also good books like:

- [Problem-Solving Strategies by Arthur Engel](http://www.springer.com/in/book/9780387982199)
- [How to Solve it by George Pólya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Solve_It)
- [The Art And Craft of Problem Solving by Paul Zeitz](https://www.amazon.it/Art-Craft-Problem-Solving/dp/0471789011)

These books contain many challenging problems. Maybe you was searching for standard form of proofs but I think it's more important to fully understand the reasoning behind a solution. The formal writing is a conseguence of it.